# How do I use Cygwin to uninstall a program I have installed with Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gmp

More specifically, I have installed Cygwin on my Windows in order to use a program for GAP which only runs on UNIX systems. This is my first time using UNIX anything and I bungled the install of GMP, so I'd like to use Cygwin to uninstall GMP and reinstall it correctly. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: How have you installed it, with setup ?